# In Another, does the curse also kill the adults?

Tags: anime, another

In the anime 'Another', the curse is seen to only kill the teenage students of the school, so my question is - does the curse also kill the adults too? By adults I refer to the various parents and the tecahers.

Comment: Did you get to the end of the show?

Comment: Yes This is a website where people ask questions and answer said questions about sci fi.

Comment: I was just asking in case you didn't want anything spoiled...

Comment: Also, I remember that the teacher committed suicide after murdering his mother, and the car accident that killed student Aya Ayano also killed both of her parents who were driving the car

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. this [wiki](https://another.fandom.com/wiki/Deaths#1998,_the_current_year_of_the_story.) lists the deaths that occurred as apart of the Calamity

> This page lists the deaths that have occurred due to class 3 grade 9's curse to the latest episode.

a couple of the adults from the 1998 Calamity are

> - Mieko Sakuragi - Died in a car accident in the same day as her daughter, Yukari.
> - Shoji Kubodera - The class teacher. He committed suicide by stabbing himself in the neck with a kitchen knife in front of the class, Monday July 13th. He also killed his elderly mother a little earlier.

we can also count The Extra's death whos very existence in 1998 is because of the Calamity due to the fact that had previously died

the page also notes that one adult who died in the 1998 Calamity but because of their location and lack of connection with Class 3-3 may not be counted as having died as a result of the Calamity

> Teruya Sakaki, a survivor of the 1987 Calamity, died in his home on May 3 of 1998; however, as he was outside Yomiyama and no longer directly connected to Class 3-3, his death may not have counted as part of the Calamity of 1998.